# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl'

Tags: c#

```
 1. my .aspx code is  

       asp:GridView ID="gvaccmaster" DataKeyNames="id"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            OnRowCancelingEdit="gridView_RowCancelingEdit"
            OnRowDeleting="gridView_RowDeleting"
            OnRowEditing="gridView_RowEditing"
            OnRowUpdating="gridView_RowUpdating"
            OnRowDataBound="gridView_RowDataBound" Font-Names="Arial"
            Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False"
            OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" CellPadding="2"
            Style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle"
            BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="2px"> <AlternatingRowStyle
            BorderStyle="None" /> <Columns> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID"
            ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="ID"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("id") %>' /> </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"
            ConvertEmptyStringToNull="False"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label
            ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtname"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>' />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv0"
            ControlToValidate="txtname" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" /> </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opening
            Balance"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="opbalance" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("openingbalance") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtopbalance" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("openingbalance") %>' /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            runat="server" ID="rfv1" ControlToValidate="txtopbalance"
            ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev4" runat="server"
            ErrorMessage="invalid opening balance" ValidationGroup="validaiton"
            ControlToValidate="txtopbalance" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationExpression="^\d+$"> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField
            HeaderText="Contact Person"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="cperson"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("contactperson") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtcperson" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("contactperson") %>' /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            runat="server" ID="rfv2" ControlToValidate="txtcperson"
            ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField
            HeaderText="Address"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="address"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtaddress" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("address") %>' /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
            runat="server" ID="rfv3" ControlToValidate="txtaddress"
            ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="validaiton" />
            </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField
            HeaderText="City"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="city"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("city") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>enter
            code here <EditItemTemplate> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcity"
            runat="server" Height="25px" Width="100px">
            <asp:ListItem>Ahmedabad</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Baroda</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Rajkot</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Udaipur</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Jaipur</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Ajmer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Jodhpur</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Bhopal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Indore</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Gwalior</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Ujjain</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Mumbai</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Pune</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Nagpur</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Nasik</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Aurangabad</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Akola</asp:ListItem> </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField
            HeaderText="State"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="state"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("state") %>' /> </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate> <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server"
            Height="25px" Width="150px"> <asp:ListItem>Gujarat</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Rajasthan</asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem>Madhya
            Pradesh</asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem>Maharashtra</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList> </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Area"> <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label
            ID="area" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("area") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="txtarea"
            runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("area") %>' />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv4"
            ControlToValidate="txtarea" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" /> </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pin Code">
            <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="pincode" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("pincode") %>' /> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtpincode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("pincode")
            %>' /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv5"
            ControlToValidate="txtpincode" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" /> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="rev3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid pincode"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" ControlToValidate="txtpincode"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\d{6}">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile">
            <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="mobile" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("mobile") %>' /> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtmobile" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("mobile")
            %>' /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv6"
            ControlToValidate="txtmobile" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" /> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="rev2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid mobile"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" ControlToValidate="txtmobile"
            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^[7-9][0-9]{9}$">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="E-Mail">
            <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="email" runat="server"
            Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' /> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtemail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>'
            /> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfv7"
            ControlToValidate="txtemail" ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" /> <asp:RegularExpressionValidator
            ID="rev1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="invalid email"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" ControlToValidate="txtemail"
            ForeColor="Red"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator> </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField> <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
            <ItemTemplate> <asp:Button ID="ButtonEdit" runat="server"
            CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" Width="50px" /> <asp:Button
            ID="ButtonDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"
            Width="50px" /> </ItemTemplate> <EditItemTemplate> <asp:Button
            ID="ButtonUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"
            ValidationGroup="validaiton" Width="60px" /> <asp:Button
            ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"
            Width="60px" /> </EditItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField> </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" /> <HeaderStyle
            BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px"
            Font-Names="Cambria" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="#CCCCCC"
            Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Blue" HorizontalAlign="Center"
            VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle> <RowStyle
            HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" /> </asp:GridView>
```

---

and code behind the page is

```
protected void btnview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
             { 
                 string query = txtsearch.Text; 

                 foreach(GridViewRow row in gvaccmaster.Rows) 
                 { 
                     row.Visible = false; 
                 } 

                 if(query.Trim() != "") 
                 { 
                     foreach (GridViewRow row in gvaccmaster.Rows)
                     { 
                         foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells) 
                         { 
                             string cellText = cell.Text; 

                             if (cell.Text == "" && cell.Controls.Count > 0) 
                             {
                                 cellText = ((LiteralControl)cell.Controls[0]).Text; 
                             } 

                             if (cellText.IndexOf(query) > -1) 
                             { 
                                 row.Visible = true; break; 
                             } 
                         } 
                     } 
                 }
                 else 
                 { 
                     foreach (GridViewRow row in gvaccmaster.Rows) 
                     { 
                         row.Visible = true; 
                     } 
                 } 
             } 

            // im getting error on line 
            //if (cell.Text == "" && cell.Controls.Count > 0) 
            //{ 
            //    cellText = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)cell.Controls[0]).Text; 
            //}
```

Comment: First of all you forgot to ask a question. Secondly, assuming that the title of your question contains the error you are getting, it should tell you the line number where the error occurs, please post the line it is referring to. I also recommend you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am performing searching operation in gridview without using sql datasource.i am getting error as.,,,   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.DataBoundLiteralControl'. I  have taken template field in the gridview so that i can perform editing and updating.

Comment: I think you can easily avoid the error by debugging when error comes. check what Type it show for the control in debug window, if you get different Types in loop add if condition to check Type and caste accordingly.

Comment: one more thing if you do not have any good reason to use <asp:Label> ignore it and use directly "Eval" (ex: `<%#Eval("id") %>`). you will be able to access string from `cell.Text`.